# enforce the decimal format for csv

Tags: reactjs, excel, csv, decimal-point

I am using [CSVLink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv) to download data from my react app. One of the columns contain a 16 digits number so when I am downloading the file the output format will change to something like this **8.1543E+15**.

```
const text = [
{ a1: "1111111111111111", a2: "0658" },
{ a1: "2222222222222222", a2: "0658" },
{ a1: "3333333333333333", a2: "0658" },
{ a1: "4444444444444444", a2: "10658" }]

 <CSVLink
       filename={props.name + ".csv"}
       target="_blank"
       data={text}
       headers={[{ label: "a1", key: "a1" }, { label: "a2", key: "a2" }]}>
       {props.name}
  </CSVLink>
```

If I will open the file with Notepad then I can see the full number but via Excel I will see **8.1543E+15** & **658**

How can I enforce the decimal format so when the user download the file he will see the full number witout the need to manually change the decimal places.

Thank you
.

Comment: Try to convert number to the string will resolve the problem

Comment: I did. Not working.

Comment: The user computer **must** see the value as text before the value is written to the worksheet. Depending on the sophistication of the user, you can either prefix the string with a non-numeric character, or have them do an **IMPORT** using Power Query or a legacy import method. If doing an IMPORT is beyond them, writing a macro for them is another option. Preceding the value with a single quote works, but the single quote will appear in the cell.  Preceding the value with a non-breaking space (or unicode zero width space) should also work, and might be more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Note that for the NBSP or ZWSP method to work, the file must be saved as a UTF-8 CSV file (with the BOM at the start of the file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The csv format has no provision to include format information for columns - so you can not enforce decimal format.

The only thing you can possibly do is force spreadsheet programs to treat the numbers as 'string'.

- If you have number "8154300000000000" to be treated as string in spreadsheet application, you need to write it as  ="8154300000000000"
- The " character is a separator in csv - that means you need to escape " character. The escape character in csv is ". That means you need to output double quotes ("") to escape single quote (").  Now your output string will be =""8154300000000000""
- Finally, your React program also needs to escape " character. The escape character for javascript is \ - but for simplicity you can enclose the string in single quote (')

You can see the working sample here..

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-cvs-large-integer-ff32p?file=/src/App.js

```
  const text = [
    { a1: '=""8154300000000000""', a2: "0658" },
    { a1: "2222222222222222", a2: "0658" },
    { a1: "3333333333333333", a2: "0658" },
    { a1: "4444444444444444", a2: "10658" }
  ];

  return (
    <CSVLink
      filename="largeNumber.csv"
      target="_blank"
      data={text}
      headers={[
        { label: "a1", key: "a1" },
        { label: "a2", key: "a2" }
      ]}
    >
      Download Me
    </CSVLink>
  );
```